# Jetpack Compose full screen navigation Dialog without statusbar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, statusbar, android-fullscreen

in my Android app with **Jetpack Compose**, I need to implement design, where app:

- does NOT have status bar at all, so it's not even visible and app can draw under it
- does have navigation bar visible

using this theme:

```xml
<style name="Theme.Launcher" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and this code in `MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This will allows app to draw under OS status bar
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            // rest of the compose code
        }
    }
}
```

On `NavGraphBuilder` when using:

- `composable` extension screen, output takes whole empty space, as expected;
- `dialog` extension with `DialogProperties( usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)` for screen, there is some **vertical margin** and screen below is clearly visible.

Using Jetpack Compose BOM `2023.06.01` and `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0`.

I have also tried to use [`enableEdgeToEdge()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity) or [`EdgeToEdgeUtils.applyEdgeToEdge(window, true)`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/6ac7c350c42f3ca4e734b3043bf88306839d6574/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/EdgeToEdgeUtils.java#L55), but the output is similar.

Same output is on Android SDK 28, 31, emulator and also real device.

Thanks for any idea how to properly setup this, so also the `dialog` delivers proper visual output as `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist)

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help. This fun is deprecated and I've tried to use Activity.enableEdgeToEdge as a replacement, which didn't help.

Comment: where do you get that information? which version are you using?

Comment: deprecation info is on Accompanist site: https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/

Comment: deprecation doesn't mean it's not working. Also, the guide is very clear : ```We recommend forking the implementation and customising it to your needs.```. 
From the actual implementation of accompanist, you know what to do.